# Как добавить еще 4 направления?Алгоритм Ли

Tags: алгоритм, delphi

Имеется код волнового алгоритма(без диагональных направлений).Можно ходить в 4 стороны.Код рабочий,но как только я пытаюсь добавить еще хотя бы 1 направление,все перестает работать.Вот код с 4 направлениями(изначальный)

```
program Project2;

{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}

uses
  SysUtils;

type
  RecCells=record
  dx,dy:Integer; {Для лучшего хранения нужных ячеек}
  end;

var
 a:array[1..10,1..10] of integer; {Основной массив (можно заменять на нужный размер}
 b,c:array[0..1000] of RecCells; {Массив для ячеек, которые нужно будет пометь как d+1 и потом заменить эти ячейки на ячейки d+1}
 n,m,l,t,u,d,s:Integer;
 finalx,finaly,startx,starty:Integer; {стартовая и финальная}
 k:char;
 ii,jj:Integer;


procedure read(k:char); {Чтения из файла. Стена тут должна быть '@', а пустое место, соответственно, ' '}
 var i,j:integer;        //upd:упростил,теперь файл не требуется
 begin
 Writeln('Vvedite razmernost');
 write('n = ');
 Readln(n);
 write('m = ');
 Readln(m);   //10,10
 for i:=1 to n do
   for j:=1 to m do
     begin
        a[i,j]:=0;   {В массиве это будет -1 и 0 (стена и пустое место)}
     end;
     a[2,2]:=-1;
     a[3,2]:=-1;
     a[1,2]:=-1;
     a[4,2]:=-1;
     a[5,3]:=-1;
     a[2,3]:=-1;
     a[5,7]:=-1;
     Writeln('Nazhmite Enter');
     Readln;

 for i:=1 to n do begin
   for j:=1 to m do
     write(a[i,j]:3);
   writeln;
 end;


 Writeln('Vvedite start');
 Write('Start x = ');
 Readln(startx);
 Write('Start y = ');
 Readln(starty);
 Writeln('Vvedite finish');
 Write('Finish x = ');
 Readln(finalx);
 Write('Finish y = ');
 Readln(finaly);

 if (a[startx,starty]=-1) or (a[finalx,finaly]=-1) then
 begin
   Writeln('Path not found');
   Readln;
   Exit;
 end;


 end;
 procedure check(i,j:integer);  {проверка на соседние ячейки, которые можно пометить, как d+1 для каждой ячейки из массива b}
 begin
  if (i>1) and (a[i-1,j]=0) then
    begin
    a[i-1,j]:=d;
    inc(l);
    c[l].dx:=i-1;
    c[l].dy:=j;
    end;
  if (j>1) and (a[i,j-1]=0) then
    begin
    a[i,j-1]:=d;
    inc(l);
    c[l].dx:=i;
    c[l].dy:=j-1;
    end;
    if (i<n) and (a[i+1,j]=0) then
    begin
    a[i+1,j]:=d;
    inc(l);
    c[l].dx:=i+1;
    c[l].dy:=j;
    end;
     if (j<m) and (a[i,j+1]=0) then
    begin
    a[i,j+1]:=d;
    inc(l);
    c[l].dx:=i;
    c[l].dy:=j+1;
    end;
  end;

procedure findway(i,j:integer); {Поиск финального пути. Идет назад по массиву к стартовой ячейке и записывает ячейку в массив b (уже финальный путь)}
 begin
 s:=0;
 a[startx,starty]:=0;
  repeat
   dec(d);
   if (i>1) and (a[i-1,j]=d) then begin dec(i); inc(s); b[s].dx:=i; b[s].dy:=j; end
   else
   if (i<n) and (a[i+1,j]=d) then begin inc(i); inc(s); b[s].dx:=i; b[s].dy:=j; end
   else
   if (j>1) and (a[i,j-1]=d) then begin dec(j); inc(s); b[s].dx:=i; b[s].dy:=j; end
   else
   if (j<m) and (a[i,j+1]=d) then begin inc(j); inc(s); b[s].dx:=i; b[s].dy:=j; end;
  until (i=startx) and (j=starty);
end;


begin
 // assign(input, 'input.txt'); reset(input);
//  assign(output, 'output.txt'); rewrite(output);
read(k);
b[1].dx:=startx; b[1].dy:=starty;
a[startx,starty]:=-2;
u:=1; d:=0;
repeat
 inc(d);
 l:=0;
 for t:=1 to u do
  begin
  check(b[t].dx,b[t].dy);
  end;
  if l=0 then begin write('NO EXIT'); exit; end; {? ?????? b ?? ?????????? ?? ???? ????? ?????? - ???? ?? ??????}
  for s:=1 to l do b[s]:=c[s]; {??????? ?? ???????????????? ??????? ? ???????? ??? ?????? ????? ?? ??????}
  u:=l;
until a[finalx,finaly]<>0;
{----------} findway(finalx,finaly);

writeln;

for ii:=1 to n do begin
   for jj:=1 to m do
     write(a[ii,jj]:3);
   writeln;
end;

writeln;

for d:=s downto 1 do write( '{ ',b[d].dx, ',',b[d].dy,' }  ');
 Readln;
end.
```

А вот код,где я попытался добавить еще 1 направление(там сбоку коммент //added)

```
program Project2;

{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}

uses
  SysUtils;

type
  RecCells=record
  dx,dy:Integer; {Для лучшего хранения нужных ячеек}
  end;

var
 a:array[1..10,1..10] of integer; {Основной массив (можно заменять на нужный размер}
 b,c:array[0..1000] of RecCells; {Массив для ячеек, которые нужно будет пометь как d+1 и потом заменить эти ячейки на ячейки d+1}
 n,m,l,t,u,d,s:Integer;
 finalx,finaly,startx,starty:Integer; {стартовая и финальная}
 k:char;
 ii,jj:Integer;


procedure read(k:char); {Чтения из файла. Стена тут должна быть '@', а пустое место, соответственно, ' '}
 var i,j:integer;        //upd:упростил,теперь файл не требуется
 begin
 Writeln('Vvedite razmernost');
 write('n = ');
 Readln(n);
 write('m = ');
 Readln(m);   //10,10
 for i:=1 to n do
   for j:=1 to m do
     begin
        a[i,j]:=0;   {В массиве это будет -1 и 0 (стена и пустое место)}
     end;
     a[2,2]:=-1;
     a[3,2]:=-1;
     a[1,2]:=-1;
     a[4,2]:=-1;
     a[5,3]:=-1;
     a[2,3]:=-1;
     a[5,7]:=-1;
     Writeln('Nazhmite Enter');
     Readln;

 for i:=1 to n do begin
   for j:=1 to m do
     write(a[i,j]:3);
   writeln;
 end;


 Writeln('Vvedite start');
 Write('Start x = ');
 Readln(startx);
 Write('Start y = ');
 Readln(starty);
 Writeln('Vvedite finish');
 Write('Finish x = ');
 Readln(finalx);
 Write('Finish y = ');
 Readln(finaly);

 if (a[startx,starty]=-1) or (a[finalx,finaly]=-1) then
 begin
   Writeln('Path not found');
   Readln;
   Exit;
 end;


 end;
 procedure check(i,j:integer);  {проверка на соседние ячейки, которые можно пометить, как d+1 для каждой ячейки из массива b}
 begin
   if (i>1) and (a[i-1,j]=0) then
     begin
       a[i-1,j]:=d;
       inc(l);
       c[l].dx:=i-1;
       c[l].dy:=j;
     end;
   if (j>1) and (a[i,j-1]=0) then
     begin
       a[i,j-1]:=d;
       inc(l);
       c[l].dx:=i;
       c[l].dy:=j-1;
     end;
   if (i<n) and (a[i+1,j]=0) then
     begin
       a[i+1,j]:=d;
       inc(l);
       c[l].dx:=i+1;
       c[l].dy:=j;
     end;
   if (j<m) and (a[i,j+1]=0) then
     begin
       a[i,j+1]:=d;
       inc(l);
       c[l].dx:=i;
       c[l].dy:=j+1;
     end;

   if (i>1) and (j<m) and (a[i-1,j+1]=0) then
   begin
     a[i+1,j+1]:=d;
     inc(l);                                //added
     c[l].dx:=i-1;
     c[l].dy:=j+1;
   end;
  end;

procedure findway(i,j:integer); {Поиск финального пути. Идет назад по массиву к стартовой ячейке и записывает ячейку в массив b (уже финальный путь)}
 begin
 s:=0;
 a[startx,starty]:=0;
  repeat
   dec(d);

   if (i>1) and (a[i-1,j]=d) then
    begin
      dec(i);
      inc(s);
      b[s].dx:=i;
      b[s].dy:=j;
    end

   else
   if (i<n) and (a[i+1,j]=d) then
    begin
      inc(i);
      inc(s);
      b[s].dx:=i;
      b[s].dy:=j;
    end
   else
   if (j>1) and (a[i,j-1]=d) then
    begin
      dec(j);
      inc(s);
      b[s].dx:=i;
      b[s].dy:=j;
    end
   else
   if (j<m) and (a[i,j+1]=d) then
    begin
      inc(j);
      inc(s);
      b[s].dx:=i;
      b[s].dy:=j;
    end
    else
    if (i>1)and (j<m) and (a[i+1,j+1]=d) then
    begin
      inc(j);
      inc(s);
      b[s].dx:=i;                                     //added
      b[s].dy:=j;
    end;

  until (i=startx) and (j=starty);
end;


begin
 // assign(input, 'input.txt'); reset(input);
//  assign(output, 'output.txt'); rewrite(output);
  read(k);
  b[1].dx:=startx;
  b[1].dy:=starty;
  a[startx,starty]:=-2;
  u:=1;
  d:=0;
repeat
  inc(d);
  l:=0;
  for t:=1 to u do
  begin
    check(b[t].dx,b[t].dy);
  end;
  if l=0 then
  begin
    write('NO EXIT');
    exit;
   end;
  for s:=1 to l do b[s]:=c[s];
  u:=l;
until a[finalx,finaly]<>0;
{----------} findway(finalx,finaly);

writeln;

for ii:=1 to n do begin
   for jj:=1 to m do
     write(a[ii,jj]:3);
   writeln;
end;

writeln;

for d:=s downto 1 do write( '{ ',b[d].dx, ',',b[d].dy,' }  ');
Readln;
end.
```

Вопрос.Почему добавленное направление не работает,что я сделал не так,где ошибка и как правильно дописать 4 направления по диагоналям?

Answer (score 1):

```
if (i>1) and (j < m) and (a[i-1,j+1]=0) then  //здесь минус
  begin 
    a[i+1,j+1]:=d;                           //а здесь плюс
```

Comment: вот тут не работает код 
 `if (i<n) and (j < m) and (a[i+1,j+1]=0) then  
  begin 
    a[i+1,j+1]:=d;`

Comment: А что значит - не работает? Вот я сделал два исправления и для 7,7-1,3 получается ` { 7,7 }  { 7,6 }  { 7,5 }  { 7,4 }  { 6,4 }  { 5,4 }  { 4,4 }  { 3,4 }  { 2,4 } { 1,4 }`

Comment: не ходит по диагоналям @mbo

Comment: При выводе матрицы направления x и y попутаны, так что не исключаю, что и ещё есть ошибки.

Comment: где попутаны направления?

Comment: При выводе на экран первый индекс идёт сверху вниз,  а в коде он используется для X

Comment: что-то я не понял(  @mbo

Comment: Ну разбирайся. Какие координаты у `a[5, 7] := -1;`?

Comment: такие же и есть,[5,7]

Comment: 5 - это что, X или Y? Строка или столбец?

Comment: Это строка( 5 ).